# Retrieve impressions of a post that was made via my Facebook App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights, impressions

There is a way to get the impressions insights of a post throught the graph api? I use my app to publish photos in the users profiles with then permission but i dont get any impressions of that post just likes, comments, reactions... I use the metric parameters from the App Insights documentation but this is what i get in all the cases:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "time": "2017-08-15T08:00:00+0000",
        "value": "0"
    },
    {
        "time": "2017-08-16T08:00:00+0000",
        "value": "0"
    },
    {
        "time": "2017-08-17T08:00:00+0000",
        "value": "0"
    },
    {
        "time": "2017-08-18T08:00:00+0000",
        "value": "0"
    },
    {
        "time": "2017-08-19T08:00:00+0000",
        "value": "0"
    },
    {
        "time": "2017-08-20T08:00:00+0000",
        "value": "0"
    },
    {
        "time": "2017-08-21T08:00:00+0000",
        "value": "0"
    }
]
```

}

I log in different test users accounts and see this specific post, create comments and put likes but there is no impressions... Can somebody help me with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: There are no insights for posts made by user profiles.

Comment: Thanks, if i need the impressions of a post made by my app what is the best publish method to do that? Right now we use the graph api but i don't know if i can use the open graph in order to get that data?

Comment: You can “need” all you want, that doesn’t make it magically come into existence. There are no insights available for posts on user profiles.